# Screenshots no longer saved in the default folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I took a screenshot today on my computer. But I saw that my computer saved my screenshot elsewhere. I didn't see it in the default screenshot folder. But just in the pictures folder. I have been looking for a solution on the internet for a long time, but could not find anything that works for my. So I want to ask if someone can help me here! Hopefully it can be fixed! Thank you in advance!

Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

[Register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wg7x.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using WinKey+PrtScrn to capture your screenshots? I'm guessing so because (assuming "Schermopname" translates to ""ScreenShots") your filename is following the standard naming convention.

My first guess is that perhaps the OS now "thinks" your main `Pictures` folder is also your `ScreenShots` folder. To test this, click in the Address Bar of an Explorer window & type: `shell:ScreenShots`, press  and see what folder you navigate to:
[image]

[image]

It also just occured to me that this may be a multi-language issue. Based on the use of `desktop.ini` files, that many of the default system folders have English names at the file system level (viewable via **PowerShell** or a **Command Prompt**). Compare the display names of folders in Explorer under This PC with the folder names seen at a console window.

If you're comfortable looking in the Registy, check the key:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
```

If Screenshots has been re-directed, you'll see an entry named:
`{b7bede81-df94-4682-a7d8-57a52620b86f}`
and its data will be the path the OS expects to find. If it doesn't exist, the OS assumes it will be a child of your Pictures folder -- whether that has been redirected or not.

So please post back with what you found with the `shell:screenshots` command, console directory listings and registry info.

---

***Update***: Looking at your Registry captrue, you have the value for the **Screenshots** folder, **`{B7BEDE81-DF94-4682-A7D8-57A52620B86F}`**, but it's pointing to `%UserProfile%\Pictures`. If `%UserProfile%` = `C:\Users\benny_Khex7ja` then deleting the value should be sufficient. Or you can edit the path to point to your **Screenshots** folder. EIther should work.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer. In explorer I typed shell: screenshots. But eventually still came back to the pictures folder. I also went to the Register there I saw this. (I will put my picture above) And I'm also using the WinKey+PrtScrn

Comment: I see the culprit in your registry. Will edit my answer..

Comment: Thank you for your help! My problem is solved! I just changed the `%UserProfile%\Picture` to `%UserProfile%\Picture\screenshot`. Thank you again for your help! And have a very nice day!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for marking my reply as `Answer`. Could you please give it an upvote as well? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever product you are using for taking the screenshot,
you have mis-configured, with a confusion between folder-name and file-name.

Instead of storing your image in the *folder* `Schermopname`,
it was stored as the *file* named `Schermopname (74)`.
I assume that the `(74)` was added by the software in order to resolve the
conflict arising from the fact that you cannot have co-residing a folder
and an image having the same name.